# Vscode Font setup?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, fonts

[image]

Can Someone tell me what is this font, I want to use it in react. Can someone help?
Thank you

Comment: Can't be sure, but possibly [Dank Mono](https://philpl.gumroad.com/l/dank-mono)

Comment: Thank you very much bro Its Dank Mono